# Clarification on .NET 4.6.2 Long Path Handling

Tags: c#, .net, path, filesystems, .net-4.6.2

With the release of .NET 4.6.2, a new way of handling long paths was implemented. I've read the release articles on it, and from what I understand:

- If I target .NET 4.6.2, I can use the System.IO classes with long paths, without having to prepend "\\?\" to them.
- This feature works on all Microsoft Oses supporting .NET 4.6.2.

Can anyone confirm this? Can I just forget worrying about "\\?\" and it will just work on all Oses supporting 4.6.2 or do I still need to use extended path syntax for previous versions of Windows, when using System.IO classes?

Edit: from further investigation, it appears that I will still need to use "\\?\somepath" for the System.IO classes, if long path support is not enabled on the OS (i.e. pre-Windows 10). Is this right?

Comment: yes it will work